# How to decode base64 API response in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, http

I am stuck in a situation where I need to decrypt the base64 encoded API response coming from the backend instead of JSON.

The response i am getting:

```
eyJzdGF0dXNDb2RlIjoiT0siLCJtZXNzYWdlIjoiU1VDQ0VTUyIsImRhdGEiOnsiZGF0YVVwZGF0ZWQiOnRydWV9LCJzdGF0dXMiOnRydWV9
```

I tried to with interceptor but getting an error

```
[$http:baddata] Data must be a valid JSON object.
```

Any help will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
$http({
  url: 'your_url',
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: [function (data) {
      // decode data with base64
      return atob(data)
  }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @bunyamiN your suggested changes are working fine, however, is there an alternate approach to do this? currently, if I go with your solution then I need to update all the apis in my project which can be difficult for me and for other team members also.

Comment: @sumitchauhan In that case you want to configure the $httpProvider. Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/43l52SzejjoTwYmn?preview) .
You can also read more about it in the [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/docs/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider#defaults)